# Change int value when clicking notification

Tags: android, notifications

I've been searching information about how to change the value of a variable when clicking a notification but I haven't fount anything.

I do no want to launch a new activity. I jus want to change the value of the variable.

Hoe can I achieve it?

Thank you in advanvece!

Comment: Where is the variable located?

Comment: The variable is located in the activity of the Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch an activity where you change the variable on it. If you don't want the activity to be seen, don't call `setContentView()`.

Comment: I do not want to launch a new activity (visible or not). I just want to change the value. I was thinking about some type of listener. Is it possible?

Comment: I believe it is not possible. What's the problem with the non-visible activity?

Comment: I didn't want to have invisible activities but if it is the only solution I'll have to accept it. I'll try to do what you tell me.